# Capturing images from a webcam and displaying on a monitor

Tags: c, linux, opencv, image-processing, camera

I want to periodically capture images through a webcam, modify the captured image and display it on a monitor. I can of course use OpenCV for that purpose, but OpenCV is big and complex. I want to have some code which can be easily ported from one system to another and therefore not depend on a big library. So my question is, is there any sample code for what I'm trying to do without using OpenCV or any other library?

Comment: To capture image from webcam you need only `ffmpeg` or `mencoder`. To make slight modifying - ImageMagick. To display - any image viewer (`feh` for example).

Comment: what type of modification? something like crop or ..?